# DB2 z/OS : how to log all sql statements and returned results by a batch application?

Tags: sql, logging, db2, rows

I am looking for a way to log all sql statements and returned rows (+sql code) in order of execution for a batch application on z/OS. (size of log is not an issue nor performance degradation due to logging / archiving -> we need to do that on a test environment)

I do not have access to application source code : just binaries.

I looked at DB2 Trace but did not find proper trace level to start to obtain that level of details.

1) Is there any DB2 trace level that will log both ?
2) Should use another strategy : some "magical" exit somewhere, etc. ?

Thanks in advance for hints
didier

Comment: Probably should be posted to ServerFault or DBA...

Comment: You probably want Optim Performance Manager -- that will log all activity by application.

Comment: The application runs on z/OS? or the application runs elsewhere and connects to DB2 on z/OS? I don't think any trace settings capture query results. [InfoSphere Optim Workload Replay](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/infosphere-optim-workload-replay) can capture queries and results.

Comment: ...why are you doing this?  Why don't you have the source code?  If it's 3rd-party code, you may run into legal issues.  It's pretty trivial to get the statements themselves, but why do you care about the results as well?

Comment: Hi guys, Thanks for the pointer to Optim Workload Replay : we'll check it out.

Comment: -> Clockwork-Muse : no legal issue in doing that for that specific case. We care about results, because we want to be able to do same thing and check if we have same results in another environment. Regards. Didier